# Copy column 0 (date column) in R after importing stock data from yahoo finance

Tags: r

I am trying to copy the date column of the data for easy access. It is located at column `0`.  I tried to clone it using  `GOOGL$DATE<- GOOGL[,0]`. The results was a `NULL` instead of the date provided.

```
getSymbols("GOOGL", 
       from ="2019-01-01", 
       to = "2019-06-30", 
       src =  "yahoo", 
       adjust =  TRUE)
GOOGL$DATE<- GOOGL[,0]
```

Comment: You may use  " " around the zero, without, it selects the 0th column, that does not exist

Comment: You should mention what library you use with `library(name_of_library)`. what tdel means is using `GOOGL[,"0"]` or `GOOGL$0`. Just imagine a table - there is no coulmn with number `0` in R.

Comment: Error in `[.xts`(GOOGL, , "0") : subscript out of bounds

Comment: Questions to SO should be *complete* and, in particular, include all `library` calls.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes in R start at 1.  There is no column 0.  The `GOOGL` object is an `xts` object whose index is the dates.  Read the documentation to the [xts](https://cran.r-project.org/package=xts) and [zoo](https://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) packages for background.

Either of these give the dates:

```
time(GOOGL)
##   [1] "2019-01-02" "2019-01-03" "2019-01-04" "2019-01-07" "2019-01-08"
##   [6] "2019-01-09" "2019-01-10" "2019-01-11" "2019-01-14" "2019-01-15"
##  [11] "2019-01-16" "2019-01-17" "2019-01-18" "2019-01-22" "2019-01-23"
##  ...etc...    

index(GOOGL)
##   [1] "2019-01-02" "2019-01-03" "2019-01-04" "2019-01-07" "2019-01-08"
##   [6] "2019-01-09" "2019-01-10" "2019-01-11" "2019-01-14" "2019-01-15"
##  [11] "2019-01-16" "2019-01-17" "2019-01-18" "2019-01-22" "2019-01-23"
##  ...etc...
```

The core data of an xts or zoo object is a numeric matrix and you can't mix dates and numbers in a matrix.  Internally the dates are stored in an `index` attribute.  Furthermore, it is not really desirable to add the date as a column in the first place.  In its current form you can use all the facilities of xts and zoo to manipulate it which is why `getSymbols` gives it in that form.

It is possible to convert an xts or zoo object to a data frame using `fortify.zoo(GOOGL)` .  That creates a data frame whose first column's name is `Index` containing the dates but unless there really is a good reason to do that it would be better not to do so.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to convert the `zoo` object to dataframe and then add `rownames` as new column

```
GOOGLE <- as.data.frame(GOOGL)
GOOGLE$Date <- as.Date(rownames(GOOGLE))
```

Or we can use `fortify.zoo` which does all of this automatically

```
zoo::fortify.zoo(GOOGL)
```

**data**

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("GOOGL", 
   from ="2019-01-01", 
   to = "2019-06-30", 
   src =  "yahoo", 
   adjust =  TRUE)
```